# Why doesn't Benigno admit his crime to Marco?

Tags: plot-explanation, talk-to-her

In Almodóvar's 2002 movie *["Talk to Her"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk_to_Her)* (Spanish: "Hable con ella"), Benigno's crime remains ambiguous to the very end: the audience is not shown, nor his best friend, Marco, ever directly told that the author is Benigno. It cannot be another and he is also convicted in the end (modern DNA testing cannot fail - even if not mentioned, plus he is incarcerated).

I understand that the director cleverly hides the rape and direct revelation to keep ... well, let's call it the "innocence" (clean conscience) of his character, Benigno. But why aren't we told? It is clear that Marco knows it: he has no doubts with the lawyer, nor he tries desperately to show the innocence (rape culpability) of his friend.

So why does the film refuse to state the obvious responsibility, at least indirectly?

I am asking because I have no recollection (for the moment) of any other (good) movie with a (deliberate) plot hole like this, I just hope that I am missing something.